# Spring Data Neo4J 4 - Order By in GraphRepository don't work

Tags: java, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

To work with a neo4j-graphdatabase standalone server i add the dependency of Spring Data Neo4j 4.0.0.M1 to my pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

Btw. i write my own CDI-Extension and work with it under JavaEE 6.
(It is tested and it works.)

I manage persons in my application. So if i want to get all persons order by the updatedTime i use this easy query with my `PersonRepository (GraphRepository<Person>)`:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends GraphRepository<Person> {

    @Query("MATCH (person:Person) " +
            "Return person " +
            "ORDER BY person.updatedTime DESC " +
            "SKIP {0} " +
            "LIMIT {1} ")
    Iterable<Person> findAll(int offset, int maxResults);
}
```

For my test i created 3 persons with 3 statements:

1.

```
"statement":"CREATE (n:Person {createdTime:946717810000,
creator:'test-151658',updatedTime:978340210000,
updater:'test-151658',sic:'sic-141226',gender:'MALE'})"
```

2.

```
"statement":"CREATE (n:Person {createdTime:946717810000,
creator:'test-151658',updatedTime:1041412210000,
updater:'test-151658',sic:'sic-141402',gender:'MALE'})"
```

3.

```
"statement":"CREATE (n:Person {createdTime:946717810000,
creator:'test-151658',updatedTime:1104570610000,
updater:'test-151658',sic:'sic-105603',gender:'MALE'})"
```

to get all persons ordered by the updatedTime DESC i use:

```
Iterable<Person> results = repository.findAll(0, 100);
```

and don't get

```
Person 1: updatedTime:1104570610000,
Person 2: updatedTime:1041412210000,
Person 3: updatedTime:978340210000
```

but

```
Person 1: updatedTime:1041412210000,
Person 2: updatedTime:978340210000,
Person 3: updatedTime:1104570610000
```

to debug it i use 
`sudo ngrep -t -d any port 7474`

...and the commit from my neo4j-server was fine:

```
    {"commit":"http://neo4j:7474/db/dat
      a/transaction/833/commit","results":[{"columns":["person"],
    "data":[{"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"266","labels":["Person"],"properties":{"creator":"test-151658","createdTime":946717810000,
    "updatedTime":1104570610000,
"updater":"test-151658",
    "sic":"sic-105603","gender":"MALE"}}],"relationships":[]}},{"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"265","labels":["Person"],
    "properties":{"creator":"test-151658",
    "createdTime":946717810000,"updat
          edTime":1041412210000,"updater":"test-151658","sic":"sic-141402","gender":"MALE"}}],
    "relationships":[]}},{"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"264",
    "labels":["Person"],"properties":{"creator":"test-151658"
    ,"createdTime":
          946717810000,"updatedTime":978340210000,
    "updater":"test-151658","sic":"sic-141226","gender":"MALE"}}],"relationships":[]}}]}],
    "transaction":{"expires":"Mon, 20 Jul 2015 10:03:42 +0000"}
    ,"errors":[]}
```

**So now my questions are:**

**1. How can i get the right ordering of my 3 persons?**

**2. Depends this problem on convertion to the `Iterable<Person>` or object-graph-mapping?**

**3. Depends this problem on caching from my neo4j-session?**

Comment: Please use 4.0.0.RC1 - there have been many fixes and features (including sorting and paging which you can use) since M1. Let us know if the issue persists though.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of people with a similar question, sorting and paging was introduced after 4.0.0 M1. Please use 4.0.0.RC1 which also contains many bug fixes.